# Keras ValueError: Unknown activation function:<lambda>

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using a lambda function to create a custom activation function but when I try to upload a checkpoint I get the error:

```
ValueError: Unknown activation function:<lambda>
```

The function is:

```
lrelu = lambda x: tf.keras.activations.relu(x, alpha=0.2)
```

and used like this:

```
Conv2D(filters=96, kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(2,2),activation=lrelu)
```

I tried to add the custom_objects with no luck:

```
model = load_model(filepath, custom_objects = {"lrelu": lrelu})
```

I know I can replace my function with an extra layer and avoid this problem, but I was wondering if there is a way to make this work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need the `Lambda` layer wrapper - minimal example below.

```py
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, Lambda
from keras.models import Model
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

lrelu = Lambda(lambda x: tf.keras.activations.relu(x, alpha=0.2))

ipt   = Input((4,4,3))
out   = Conv2D(3, 1, activation=lrelu)(ipt)
model = Model(ipt, out)
model.compile('adam', 'mse')

x = np.random.randn(32,4,4,3)
model.fit(x, x)
```

```py
32/32 [==============================] - 6s 201ms/sample - loss: 2.1475
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is using tensorflow.keras which is not the same as just keras. And because I'm using a custom implementation I cannot switch

Comment: @joaquin7 It still works - and in the future, best to specify your import sources (e.g. `from keras`)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it seems that this is an issue with Keras.

Work-around is to add a separate Activation Layer:

```
model.add(Dense(units=128))
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: custom_activation(x, salience_array[0])))
```

Note: To save and load a model, use `Lambda()` instead of `Activation()`.

Reference: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8880